# Pandas: Group By and Conditional Sum and Add Back to Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like below:

```
ID  Num  Letter  Count
1   17   D       1
1   12   D       2
1   13   D       3
2   17   D       4
2   12   A       5
2   16   D       1
3   16   D       1
```

The objective is to sum 'Count' value for each 'ID' when 'Num' is (17 or 12) and 'Letter' is 'D', and also add the calculation back to the original data frame in 'Total'.

Below is expected data frame:

```
ID  Num  Letter  Count Total
1   17   D       1     3   
1   12   D       2     3   
1   13   D       3     3 
2   17   D       4     4 
2   12   A       5     4 
2   16   D       1     4
3   16   D       1     0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is replace non matched values to `0` in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then is used [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum`:

```
mask = df['Num'].isin([17,12]) & df['Letter'].eq('D')
df['Total'] = df['Count'].where(mask, 0).groupby(df['ID']).transform('sum')
print (df)
   ID  Num Letter  Count  Total
0   1   17      D      1      3
1   1   12      D      2      3
2   1   13      D      3      3
3   2   17      D      4      4
4   2   12      A      5      4
5   2   16      D      1      4
6   3   16      D      1      0
```